# Move files from one dir to another and add to each files name in the new directory

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line, cp

I need to move each *.lis file in its current directory to a new directory and add to the file's existing filename for an application to pickup the file with the new name.

For example:

```
Move /u01/vista/vmfiles/CompressGens.lis and /u01/vista/vmfiles/DeleteOnline.lis
to 
/u01/vista/Migration_Logs/LIS.BHM.P.MIGRATION_LOGS.FBA."$(date '+%m%d%y%H%M%S')"CompressGens.lis
and
/u01/vista/Migration_Logs/LIS.BHM.P.MIGRATION_LOGS.FBA."$(date '+%m%d%y%H%M%S')"DeleteOnline.lis
```

What I started out with in my script:

```
cp -f /u01/vista/vmfiles/*.lis /u01/vista/Migration_Logs/LIS.BHM.P.MIGRATION_LOGS.FBA."$(date '+%m%d%y%H%M%S')"*.lis
```

There are multiple *.lis in the /u01/vista/vmfiles/ directory, and depending on the system and day, the *.lis files will not always be the same.  Sometimes it is "DeleteOnline.lis" and CompressGens.lis but not ArchiveGens.lis.  Then the next day will be CompressGens.lis and ArchiveGens.lis.

So I will need to get the *.lis filenames in the /u01/vista/vmfiles/ directory, and then move each one.

Comment: @shelter, Sorry for not adding the formatting the code I posted. Tired and just didn't pay attention to the right pane. I'll remember to use that next time.

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop, so that you can do one file at a time.

```
ls -1tr *.lis | while read File
do
    cp -p $File ../Migration_Logs/${File%.lis}.$(date '+%m%d%y%H%M%S').CompressGens.lis &&
    mv $File ../Migration_Logs/${File%.lis}.$(date '+%m%d%y%H%M%S').DeleteOnline.lis
done
```

${File%.lis} is the bash/korn means of stripping that suffix - see ksh or bash man page.
The "&&" idiom is in order only to mv the file to the 2nd archived name if the copy for the 1st archived file works.

Answer (score 0):

@Abe Crabtree, Thanks for the help in pointing me in the right direction.  Below is the final code that worked.

```
ls -1tr *.lis | while read File
do
    mv $File /u01/vista/Migration_Logs/LIS.BHM.P.MIGRATION_LOGS.FBA.$(date '+%m%d%y%H%M%S').${File%.lis}.lis
done
```

Comment: PS - .${File%.lis}.lis is the same as $File.
But in any case as far as I can tell you are copying the file to a location, and then mv'ing the file on top of the copy, which would be odd.
Have I understood that right?

Comment: I upvoted.  Let me know if it doesn't show.  I got paste happy.  I'll update it.

Comment: I did the upvoted, and gives the message, "Thanks for the feedback!  Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score.  I guess they want to make sure I'm not a robot.  I have an account now on SO.  I'll keep posting, and will build the rep.  Thanks again for the help. :)